# Permission about apache files

Tags: linux, apache, permissions

I have a really strange problem about the permission of Apache. When I copy a directory or file to /var/www/html and visit it from my browser, it says I don't have permission. But when I make a new directory or file with the exactly same name, path, owner, group and permission, I can visit it from my browser.

The owner of the file is root and the permission of it is -rw-r--r--. I used to try some more open permission but is doesn't work, too.

By the way, my system is centos 6.0.

Comment: You don't have a htaccess file limiting access? and have you tried setting your folders to 755 and files to 644?

Comment: @Killrawr I have no htaccess file. And I also have tried and couldn't work.

Comment: What about the permissions on the user account, your using?

Comment: The user is in the group wheel and I use sudo to do these things. But when I use root to do this, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check for directory settings in apache config files. You can look for details here; http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory